# Motherboard no post issue. ASRock x370 Fatal1ty Gaming X

Tags: motherboard, post, issue-tracking

a new build, that I almost finished today won't post.

After the push of the power button purple led's light up for a couple of seconds, after which they are replaced by blinking red ones. The lights keep blinking as long as the system runs, but after a certain amount of time (x<30sec)  it shuts down and starts again after a couple of seconds. This loop continues seemingly indefinitely.

The motherboard also has a digital display with 2 digit capacity, which has 2 zeroes blinking as the system runs. I assume it shows boot progress, but unsure.

BIOS version of the motherboard as per the sticker on the BIOS chip is P5.90. My CPU (and all Ryzen 2000 series) is supposed to be supported as of version P4.6 and the Ryzen 3000 series as of version P5.5 by this motherboard.

As the GPU has two power intake slots, I initally tried two separate PCI-e cables, then switched to one with an 8+6 end.

Hardware:

CPU - AMD Ryzen 7 2700x

GPU- Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2070S

Motherboard - ASRock Fatal1ty x370 Gaming X

RAM - G.SKILL AEGIS DDR4-3200 32GB (16GBx2)

PSU - Fractal Design ION+ 760P

I already tried:

-GPU / No GPU startup (I know that this CPU doesn't have an integrated GPU)

-no RAM startup (keeps restart looping)

-no CPU startup (no restart loop)

-1 Memory on each lane at each startup (with both)

-Resetting CMOS (jumper/battery/both at the same time)

I already contacted ASRock and the seller, but am writing in a couple of forums as well, in case it actually is a trivial problem, although I've already seen similar unresolved threads on this issue with different builds.

Any helpful advice on the problem is appreciated.

Comment: What does the manual say about the behavior of the LED's you mention?

Comment: Is your processor on the supported list?>>>>>>>>https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Gaming%20X/index.asp#CPU

Comment: See page 32 of this pdf>>>>>https://download.asrock.com/Manual/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Gaming%20X.pdf

Comment: @spikey_richie There is no section about that in the manual, that is included in the package. According to the manual linked by Moab it is a cpu connection issue. How likely is it, that the cpu is damaged, even though it was very carefully installed?

Comment: @Moab Yes, it is in there. Also where did you find that manual?

Comment: Did you run the 4/8-pin connector from your PSU to the CPU power input header on your motherboard? I think it might be labelled as (1) in the manual on page 7/the bottom of page 30.

Comment: @spikey_richie I did. I just tried it again with resetting cmos beforehand. Same result.

Comment: @eQuinox here>>>>https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Gaming%20X/index.asp

Comment: Sounds like either a bent pin or the (processor or motherboard) is DOA.  What you describe indicates the system cannot even POST.

Comment: I really didn't want to believe something is broken, but if no further ideas come up, I can only hope for a replacement from the reseller. Thank you for all the responses so far.

Comment: Have you tried removing the RAM and see if you get a different LED/error/beep code?

Comment: @spikey_richie I did - same result. I also tried running it without a CPU, in which case it doesn't do the restart loop. The motherboard makes no  beeps whatsoever.